# After I filter my data, the environment shows it same data size

Tags: sql, r, database, sqldf, r-package

[image]

As the problems in this picture show, after I filter data twice, the `buyer_dormant` and `buyer_converted` still have same `obs` as buyer_before_20161222.

The console didn't show any errors during the filter process. So I am very confused about what was happened.

When I tried to test data to see where went wrong, I filtered `order_amount==0 & 20170222<order_date<=20170522` in table `buy_converted`. The result is supposed to be *no result*, however it returned `order_amount=1`.

I am very confused about my condition, I don't know what I am missing.

Any advice will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have your SQL queries phrased correctly? For the first sql query, try `"SELECT customer_id, order_amount, order_date FROM buyer_before_20161222 WHERE (order_amount <=0) AND (order_date BETWEEN 2016122 AND 20170222)"` and see if that works.

If you just want the `customer_id` for the described groups of dormant and converted buyers, try the code below written using `dplyr`:

Customers who bought something before 201612222:

```
buyer_before_2016122 <- order_table %>% 
    filter(order_amount>=1, order_date < 20161222) %>%
    select(customer_id)
```

Customers who didn't buy anything between 20161222 and 20170222, filtered for the customers who DID buy something before 20161222, aka dormant buyers:

```
 buyer_dormant  <- order_table %>%
    filter(between(order_date, 20161222, 20170222), order_amount <= 0, 
    customer_id %in% buyer_before_2016122$customer_id )
```

Customers who bought between 20170222 and 20170522, filtered for dormant buyers, aka converted buyers:

```
buyer_converted <- order_table %>% 
    filter(between(order_date, 20170222, 20170522), order_amount >= 1, 
    customer_id %in% buyer_dormant$customer_id )
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just tried to rewrite in your way, but environment showed buyer_dormant has 0 obs.

Comment: Is that not the desired result? I can see you had already filtered so that `buyer_before_20161222` had `order_amount >=1`, so clearly filtering again for `order_amount <=0` would leave no observations. If this isn't the desired result, I think you need to think about what you are trying to filter for, because the code seems like it's working now.

Comment: It is not the desired result.                                                                         
In  `buyer_before_20161222`,`order_amount>=1` is constrained in time period `order_date<20161222`.  And `order_amount<=0` was intended to find customers who didn't purchase during `2016122 <=order_date<= 20170222` based on `buyer_before_20161222`. So there should be some data since I can find some customers who satisfy these condition on my csv files.

Comment: The way you have written it now, the dplyr filter ( `filter(order_amount >=1, order_date < 20161222)`) is not "constrained"--it will return only observations with a positive nonzero order amount AND an order date before 20161222. In other words, all the observations with order dates after 20161222 will be filtered out. To include them, one possible way would be to add `| order_date >= 20161222` to your conditional statement. The same goes for the SQL queries you have written--two conditions chained by `AND` do not "constrain" each other in the manner you described.

Comment: Thank you very much. Probably because of my poor English, I didn't express my condition explicitly. First: the outcome of dplyr filter is what I want - I want to find customer who purchased(in this case `order_amount>=1`) before 20161222. Second: what I want in `buyer_dormant` is find customer who stopped buying during `2016122 <=order_date<= 20170222`from `buyer_before_20161222`. And then find customers who restarted purchase again from `customer_dormant`. So, I think it is probably right  to use`&` in this circumstances?

Comment: Ah in that case it looks like you're having some difficulty distinguishing between filtering your observations vs. filtering the customers. Check my edit and see if that helps you out.

Comment: Thx for helping! I will check~

Comment: Glad it helped! Consider hitting the accept button if it solved your problem, or feel free to pursue a better solution :) And welcome to stackoverflow!